# Problems w/ PHP timestamp on Blog Post

Tags: php, datetime

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now, so I'm looking for any insights you may have.  I have been using the following to input a timestamp on user posts:

```
//Timeframe
$date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$start_date = new DateTime($date_time); //Time of post
$end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates 
if($interval->y >= 1) {
    if($interval == 1)
        $time_message = $interval->y . " year ago"; //1 year ago
    else 
        $time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; //1+ year ago
}
else if ($interval-> m >= 1) {
    if($interval->d == 0) {
        $days = " ago";
    }
    else if($interval->d == 1) {
        $days = $interval->d . " day ago";
    }
    else {
        $days = $interval->d . " days ago";
    }


    if($interval->m == 1) {
        $time_message = $interval->m . " month " . $days;
    }
    else {
        $time_message = $interval->m . " months " . $days;
    }

}
else if($interval->d >= 1) {
    if($interval->d == 1) {
        $time_message = "Yesterday";
    }
    else {
        $time_message = $interval->d . " days ago";
    }
}
else if($interval->h >= 1) {
    if($interval->h == 1) {
        $time_message = $interval->h . " hour ago";
    }
    else {
        $time_message = $interval->h . " hours ago";
    }
}
else if($interval->i >= 1) {
    if($interval->i == 1) {
        $time_message = $interval->i . " minute ago";
    }
    else {
        $time_message = $interval->i . " minutes ago";
    }
}
else {
    if($interval->s < 30) {
        $time_message = "Just now";
    }
    else {
        $time_message = $interval->s . " seconds ago";
    }
}
```

In the html I have it outputting as:

```
<span class='comment-date'>$time_message</span>
```

Everything was working fine until recently, I didn't notice until a few days ago but I suspect it began when the year changed to 2019.  What's happening is on some of the posts I'm getting the following error:

```
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\LEARN_123\includes\classes\Post.php on line 311
```

Line 311 refers to `if($interval == 1)` in the above code.  I'm also noticing that for posts that are over 1 year old, it's not deferring to the `else` statement `$time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; //1+ year ago`.  For some it just says 1 year ago, others I'm getting the `Notice:`

I've been going through this but can't seem to figure it out.  Can anyone see what might be happening, or have any leads on how I can correct this?

Comment: Just a simple typo. since `$interval` is defined as a `DateInterval` object, it can't be converted in the `$interval == 1` conditional..  It should be `$interval->y == 1`

Comment: dont try to reinvent the wheel. checkout this library. they figured most of the time issues out for you and make it easy https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ or https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @fyrye...omg.  I've been on this thing for days now.  Why didn't I see that!  lol  yes that most defn. solved the notice problem.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close out the question & keep things tidy, I thought I would post the answer here.  As pointed out in the comments, I'm receiving the `Notice:` on these b/c my conditional `if($interval == 1)` is not able to be converted since variable `$interval` is defined as a `DateInterval` object.  The syntax was corrected to `if($interval->y == 1)` & this now functions as expected.

I'm trying to appreciate the avalanche that the small things can create, but sometimes it's just a pain in the a$$ too.

Answer (score 0):

`if($interval == 1)` should be  `if($interval->y == 1)`

Also every where you ask `if($interval->y|m|d|h|i|s==1`
you don't need the `$time_message = $interval->y|m|d|h|i|s . " frame ago";`
it could more simply be  `$time_message = "1 frame ago";` 
where frame = year, month, day, hour, minute, second

or you could simplify more and get rid of the extra if/else statements with something like the following:

```
$time_message = $interval->y|m|d|h|i|s . " frame" . ($interval->y|m|d|h|i|s > 1 ? "s " : " ") . ago";
```